# How do I clear the jmeter results from dashboard on multiple runs?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm currently running jmeter in NON-gui mode and I want to generate a report after each run.
The problem I have is that the results are being added in the jmeter dashboard after each run and are not cleared. How can I generate the report only with the last run?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the jtl file saved for the last test run then it's quite easy to generate dashboard result specifically for that test from the jtl file.

Execute the below command

```
./jmeter -g <jtl file> -o <output folder>
```

Answer (score 0):

jmeter -n -t (path to your jmx files is) -l (path and name of the jtl file) Example: jmeter -n -t C:\QA\test.jmx -l C:\QA\testresults.jtl this will make a different .jtl file based on the name you give it.